# Dynamic Dropdrown VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create  an excel drop down in vba.
I am storing the values which I want in drop down in a named range, I want to use the name of the range in the code while creating drop down like below

```
Sheet1.Range("O3:O28").Name = "test"
    With Range("rng_expensecategory").Offset(2, 0).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
         xlBetween, Formula1:="=& test"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

But the line `xlBetween, Formula1:="=& test"` is giving me an error.

Is there a turnaround or some other way which i can use to refer to the name range in the above code

Comment: not sure you need the & just the range name Formula1:="=TEST" or Formula1:="=" & strRangeName

Comment: `Formula1:= "= Sheet1!test"`

Comment: "=test" the "&" is not valid there. PS: Did you try macro recorder? The code was straight forward and performed correctly by macro recorder.